# Why am I stuck in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Please help me fix my code. I tried both but I'm still stuck even if I already inputted values 1 - 100.

OPTION 1 :

```
        Class_Record = input('Enter name & grades in math,physics and chemistry, separated by a space: ')
        Data = Class_Record.split(" ")
        Math = float(Data[1])
        Physics = float(Data[2])
        Chemistry = float(Data[3])
        while (Math<0 or Math>100): 
            Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
        while (Physics<0 or Physics>100):
            Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
        while (Chemistry<0 or Chemistry>100):
            Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
        else:
            average = ((Math+Physics+Chemistry)/3)
            Record[Data[0]] = "%0.2f" % average
```

OPTION 2:

```
        Class_Record = input('Enter name & grades in math,physics and chemistry, separated by a space: ')
        Data = Class_Record.split(" ")
        Math = float(Data[1])
        Physics = float(Data[2])
        Chemistry = float(Data[3])
        while (Math<0 or Math>100): 
            Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
            if (Math>0 and Math<100):
                break
        while (Physics<0 or Physics>100):
            Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
            if (Physics>0 and Physics<100):
                break
        while (Chemistry<0 or Chemistry>100):
            Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
            if (Chemistry>0 and Chemistry<100):
                break
```

If you have any ideas how to fix this, please tell me! Thank you so much!

Comment: You change only variable "Class_Record" in the loops but check other variables in the loop conditions.

Comment: If `Math` (for example) is out of range, you prompt the user for a new value for `Class_Record` - but you don't do anything that would actually change the value of `Math`, so it's still out of range, and will remain out of range forever.  That assignment to `Math` early in the code was a one-time event, you haven't permanently made `Math` depend on the value it was calculated from.

Comment: After every `input` you need to get the math, physics and chemistry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
Class_Record = input('Enter name & grades in math,physics and chemistry, separated by a space: ')
while True:
    Data = Class_Record.split(" ")
    Math = float(Data[1])
    Physics = float(Data[2])
    Chemistry = float(Data[3])
    if (Math < 0 or Math > 100):
        Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
        continue
    if (Physics < 0 or Physics > 100):
        Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
        continue
    if (Chemistry < 0 or Chemistry > 100):
        Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
        continue
    average = ((Math + Physics + Chemistry) / 3)
    print(Data[0], "%0.2f" % average)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def get_grades(record):
    Data = Class_Record.split(" ")
    Math = float(Data[1])
    Physics = float(Data[2])
    Chemistry = float(Data[3])
    return(Math, Physics, Chemistry)


Class_Record = input('Enter name & grades in math,physics and chemistry, separated by a space: ')

Math, Physics, Chemistry = get_grades(Class_Record)

while (Math<0 or Math>100): 
    Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
    Math, Physics, Chemistry = get_grades(Class_Record)
while (Physics<0 or Physics>100):
    Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
    Math, Physics, Chemistry = get_grades(Class_Record)
while (Chemistry<0 or Chemistry>100):
    Class_Record = input('Error. Please only enter 1-100. Try again!')
    Math, Physics, Chemistry = get_grades(Class_Record)


average = ((Math+Physics+Chemistry)/3)
```